# How to stop adding h1 content as h1 id

Tags: docpad

When i use docpad with marked plugin and render *.html.md from

```
# mytitle
```

i get

```
<h1 id="mytitle-">mytitle<h1>
```

or

```
<h1 id="-">MyNotANSITitle<h1>
```

Is it docpad, docpad-plugin-marked or marked thing?

(can't check it with multimarkdown, can't install it on Win7)

Answer (score 0):

you mean you don't want to get the id generated for you out of the box? this is actually not a bad feature, but if you want to change it I guess I can do this https://github.com/chjj/marked#overriding-renderer-methods